# tomcat linux folder name case issue

Tags: java, tomcat

I have a linux server.
I have 2 folders in root of this server:

```
Tomcat2
tomcat2
```

Please note case of the first letter.

Each of tomcats has the same application in webapps folder. In the first case (Tomcat2) it prints 'Hello 1', in the second case (tomcat2) it prints 'Hello 2'.

I run startup.sh in Tomcat2/bin folder.
But I see 'hello 2' in the logs.

Why? I know linux is case sensitive, but is it a bug? I use tomcat 6.0.14. Was it fixed or it's not an issue?

Comment: check your path.  which tomcat directory is in the path.  check your CATALINA_HOME environment variable.  which tomcat directory does it contains.  The answer to your question lies therein.

Comment: Thank you, but I don't think so, I used 2 identical tomcats, downloaded from official site. All I did is placed them to 2 mentioned folders.